gmavenplus plugin unable to resolve class for dependencies
I have a maven project where i have some groovy classes in test folder, there are no java classes in the project neither in main nor in test. Infact the main in this project is empty, this is designed to contain only BDD tests written in Spock. I have included the application jar as part of the dependencies however during the compilation phase gmaven-plus is throwing error unable to find class file for all the classes from the main application. Below is my pom file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.spas.shiproute</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.spas.shiproute.routepricer</groupId>
    <artifactId>route-pricer-bdd</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.14</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.14</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.spas.shiproute.routepricer</groupId>
            <artifactId>route-pricer-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-M3-groovy-4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-M3-groovy-4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.athaydes</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-reports</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1-groovy-4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.spas.shiproute.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>profile</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>bdd</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>compileTests</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSources>
                                <testSource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </testSource>
                            </testSources>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                                <version>4.0.13</version>
                                <type>pom</type>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Specification*</include>
                                <include>**/*Spec*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-test</id>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

Below is the error i am facing
C:\spas\Dev\work\shiproute\routepricer\route-pricer-bdd\src\test\groovy\com\spas\shiproute\bddshiproute\BDConfig.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class com.spas.shiproute.routepricer.main.RoutePricingConfiguration
 @ line 10, column 1.
   import com.spas.shiproute.routepricer.main.RoutePricingConfiguration
   ^

I checked using maven dependency tree, the version is present.

Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you. You cannot expect anyone to debug invisible code and tell you what is wrong just by looking at a POM.

my bet is com.spas.shiproute.routepricer:route-pricer-service dependency is spring-boot executable jar.

@AndreyB.Panfilov Absolutely bang on, thanks. It helped

As indicated by the comment from @Andrey the router-price-service was a spring boot executable. I added another build configuration with produces non executable jar and after that i was able successfully import the project
